# Goal (directive) failed: user:main Prolog swi

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

```
may(_,[],[]).
may(num(U),[est(C1,N1,NT1)|T1],[est(C1,N1,NT1)|T2]):-
   U =< NT1,
   may(num(U),T1,T2).

min(_,[],[]).
min(num(U),[est(C2,N2,NT2)|T3],[est(C2,N2,NT2)|T4]):-
    U > NT2,
    min(num(U),T3,T4).

main:-
   U is 2.0,
   mayores(num(U),
      [ est(3,"J",3.1), est(6,"P",4.5), est(7,"L",2.0), est(4,"R",1.5),
        est(2,"C",4.7), est(5,"F",2.0), est(9,"A",3.5), est(11,"K",4.8),
        est(8,"M",2.4), est(15,"S",1.5), est(17,"D",0.5), est(19,"G",2.0)
      ],
      T2), 
   menores(num(U),
      [ est(3,"J",3.1), est(6,"P",4.5), est(7,"L",2.0), est(4,"R",1.5),
        est(2,"C",4.7), est(5,"F",2.0), est(9,"A",3.5), est(11,"K",4.8),
        est(8,"M",2.4), est(15,"S",1.5), est(17,"D",0.5), est(19,"G",2.0)
      ],
      T4), 
   write(T4),
   write(T2),
   halt.
:- main.
```

The code needs to separate into different list the values <=2 and the values >2. but it gave me this error when i run it into ideone.

```
Goal (directive) failed: user:main.
```

Comment: You are using `mayores` and `may` ...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, prefer to use the toplevel in place of `halt/0` or `write/1` in your programs. Thus:

```
t2_t4(T2, T4) :-
   Es = [ est(3,"J",3.1), est(6,"P",4.5), est(7,"L",2.0), est(4,"R",1.5),
          est(2,"C",4.7), est(5,"F",2.0), est(9,"A",3.5), est(11,"K",4.8),
          est(8,"M",2.4), est(15,"S",1.5), est(17,"D",0.5), est(19,"G",2.0)
      ],
   U is 2.0,
   mayores(num(U), Es, T2), 
   menores(num(U), Es, T4).

?- t2_t4(T2, T4).
false.
```

Unfortunately, this fails. To reduce the source of failure, reduce the size of data and the number of goals. I finished at:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*(_).

menores(_, [], _/*[]*/).
menores(num(U), [est(C2,N2,NT2)|T3], _/*[est(C2,N2,NT2)|T4]*/):-
    U > NT2,
    * menores(num(U),T3,T4).

t2_t4(T2, T4) :-
   Es = [ /* est(3,"J",3.1), est(6,"P",4.5), est(7,"L",2.0), est(4,"R",1.5),
          est(2,"C",4.7), est(5,"F",2.0), est(9,"A",3.5), est(11,"K",4.8),
          est(8,"M",2.4), est(15,"S",1.5), est(17,"D",0.5), */
          est(19,"G",2.0)
      ],
   U is 2.0,
   * mayores(num(U), Es, T2), 
   menores(num(U), Es, T4).
```

So the actual problem is that `menores` is only defined for the case where the elements are smaller. If they are equal or greater `menores` fails. You need to state that explicitly, too. Same argument for `mayores`. Why not put both into a single predicate?
Also, there is no need to use `num/1`.

```
mayores_menores(_,[], [], []).
mayores_menores(U,[E|Es],[E|Mays],Mens):-
   E = est(_,_,NT),
   U =< NT,
   mayores_menores(U,Es,Mays,Mens).
mayores_menores(U,[E|Es],Mays,[E|Mens]):-
   E = est(_,_,NT),
   U > NT,
   mayores_menores(U,Es,Mays,Mens).


t2_t4x(T2, T4) :-
   Es = [ est(3,"J",3.1), est(6,"P",4.5), est(7,"L",2.0), est(4,"R",1.5),
          est(2,"C",4.7), est(5,"F",2.0), est(9,"A",3.5), est(11,"K",4.8),
          est(8,"M",2.4), est(15,"S",1.5), est(17,"D",0.5), est(19,"G",2.0)
      ],
   mayores_menores(2.0, Es, T2, T4).
```